# Javascript Date.toJSON don't get the timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Well the problem is that I was using code like this:

```
new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)
```

to get my date as `YYYY-MM-DD` string, then I use it like parameter in some mysql queries and in some condition statements. In the end of the day I wasn't getting the right date since it was still in the previous day (my timezone offset is +2/3 hours).

I haven't noticed that the `toJSON` method does not take into account your timezone offset, so I've ended up with this hacky solution:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours( today.getHours()+(today.getTimezoneOffset()/-60) );
console.log(today.toJSON().slice(0, 10));
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

- Here is the test code: http://jsfiddle.net/simo/qwhYw/
- JavaScript [toJSON Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON)
- JavaScript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Please don't use w3schools as a reference. For ECMAScript issues, please reference the standard, e.g. for [Date.prototype.toJSON](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.44).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Date objects in ECMAScript are internally UTC. The timezone offset is used for local times.

The specification for [Date.prototype.toJSON](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.44) says that it uses [Date.prototype.toISOString](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.43), which states that "the timezone is always UTC". What your solution is doing is offsetting the UTC time value of the date object by the timezone offset.

Consider adding your own method to Date.prototype, e.g.

```
Date.prototype.toJSONLocal = function() {
  function addZ(n) {
    return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
  }
  return this.getFullYear() + '-' + 
         addZ(this.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + 
         addZ(this.getDate());
}
```

#### Edit

If you want to squeeze extra performance, the following should be faster:

```
Date.prototype.toJSONLocal = (function() {
    function addZ(n) {
        return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
    }
    return function() {
      return this.getFullYear() + '-' +
             addZ(this.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
             addZ(this.getDate());
    };
}())
```

But that smacks of premature optimisation, so unless you are calling it thousands of times in a very short period, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Ok this is what I should do from the beginning, so I'll mark your answer, but can you tell me if this code is faster in terms of execution:
    `Date.prototype.toJSONLocal = function() {
        var local = new Date(this);
        local.setHours( this.getHours()+(this.getTimezoneOffset()/-60) );
        return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
    }`

Comment: Well the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/simo/F4VuF/ I don't seem to get the code blocks in comments here..

Comment: Since the timezone offset is returned in minutes, you can use the somewhat simpler and shorter `local.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() - this.getTimezoneOffset());`. Note also that timezones aren't all even hours (some are 15 minutes), using minutes keeps everything as integers. As for peformance, you'll need to test in different browsers. But I suspect that unless you're calling it thousands of times, speed is moot.

Comment: Oh, and one reason to not use toJSON is that it's an ES5 method so not supported by older browsers, whereas ECMA-262 ed 3 support is ubiquitous.

Comment: Yes, if you have to support IE6 or IE7, you'll want to shim in support for .toJSON(). [JScript 5.8 support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [IE8 includes JScript 5.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript)

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't noticed that the toJSON method don't take into account your timezone offset

But it does, it converts the local-time to Zulu (look at the end of the string: Z)

```
new Date( "2012-01-02T03:04:05+02:00" ).toJSON()
"2012-01-02T01:04:05.000Z"
```

Comment: Alright but I want my date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format as easy as possible. What `toJSON` returns by default isn't working for me.

Comment: You can only get year / month / day in the client time-zone and / or in UTC. In all other time-zones you need to convert manually (form UTC), or parse the date in php considering the time-zone it contains.

Comment: toJSON doesn't "convert the local time to Zulu", Date objects are always in UTC, it's when presenting dates in human readable form that they consider the local timezone offset to show a local time.