# toJSON function from Date object substracting one day

Tags: javascript, date

I'm doing some date manipulation in javascript using `Date` object.
I lost like one hour to understund a bug : Right after initialization, I used `.toJSON()` function and my date was decremented by one. Here's a code sample of what I was doing :

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDate()); // print "19"
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1); // print "18"
var formated = date.toJSON().substr(0, 10); // print "2013-09-17"
```

Suddenly the date moved from 18 to 17.
So to be sure I tried this directly into the developer console :

```
new Date(2013, 09, 19)
Sat Oct 19 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)) // date "19" as it should
new Date(2013, 09, 19).toJSON()
"2013-10-18T22:00:00.000Z" // date "18" as it shouldn't
```

Now my question is simply "why ?".

Is it possible that this come from my configuration or else ?

Is it a bug ? If yes is it a known bug ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look more carefully :

```
new Date(2013, 09, 19);
=> Sat Oct 19 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Two things are important here :

1. The hour : `00:00:00`
2. The Timezone : `+0200`

When you then call `.toJSON`, it will convert it in GMT + 0.

So `00:00:00 - 2hr` = `Today -1, hour being 22:00:00`.

Now take a look at :

```
new Date(2013, 09, 19).toJSON()
=> "2013-10-18T22:00:00.000Z"
```

One day before, but hour set to `22:00:00`

That's the reason : switching from `GMT+0200` to `GMT+0`.

Now for the solution, someone already asked it : [Javascript Date.toJSON don't get the timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382606/javascript-date-tojson-dont-get-the-timezone-offset) ;)

Comment: Thx I should have though about it...I'll validate

Comment: Thanks. I hope the link to the other answer will help you nail the solution ;)

Comment: My solution was "Don't use that function ever again". But now I know \o/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no bug here, just checkout the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string is in GMT (that's what the `Z` at the end means). Your local time is two hours ahead of that. So midnight on the 19th in your timezone is 22:00 on the 18th in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the -2 hours time offset.
Try to do

```
YourDate.setHours(0, -YourDate.getTimezoneOffset(), 0 0);
```

It will be a correct date.