# jQuery set current Date to input type="datetime-local"

Tags: jquery, date, datetime

I have the following html

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="startDate">
```

with the default format: `dd.mm.yyyy mm:hh`

I would like to set it`s default value to the current local time of my client with jQuery.

So far I have tried different solutions on this page but nothing worked.

For example

```
$("#startDate").val(new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 1);
$("#startDate").val(new Date().toDateString());
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Your html input doesn't have an id.

Comment: fixed, it was just wrong here but not in my code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you want to set the current date:

```
$("#startDate").val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,19));
```

Comment: it was just wrong here but right in my code. With `.toJSON().slice(0,19)` it works now. Is there a way to get the local time from user? I'm in GMT+2 but it returns GMT+0

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382606/javascript-date-tojson-dont-get-the-timezone-offset

Comment: this wont always return the correct date in local timezone