# pre-populating date input field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I am trying to prepopulate a date into an html "date" input field, but it ignores the values I try to pass:

```
<html>
...
<input id='date' type='date'>
...
</html>

<script>
...
var myDate = new Date();
$("#date").val(myDate);
...
```

I have also tried passing the date object as a string

```
var myDate = new Date().toDateString();
$("#date").val(myDate);
```

When I open the form, the date field is blank.  If I eliminate the type="date" tag, the value shows up as a string, but then I don't have access to the datepicker.  How do I pre-populate a date input and still have use of the datepicker?  I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: `var myDate = new Date();` not `var myDate = new.Date();`. BTW, good reading on this at http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today

Comment: The value needs to be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format for it to work.  I figured that out by looking at the value of the input field after picking a date from the picker.  DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Ptrgy/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It must be set in ISO-format.

```
(function () {
    var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        field = document.querySelector('#date');
    field.value = date;
    console.log(field.value);

})()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZ46K/

Comment: except that toISOString will give you a UTC date which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: This is a BAD ANSWER because it will likely lead to very hard to track down bugs - because, as terrinecold noted, it will give you a UTC date. If your date is in a different timezone, it might RESULT IN A DIFFERENT DATE than the one you started with(in your local timezone).

Comment: @martixy: terrinecold already gave the exact same comment *three years ago* without being rude.

Comment: It isn't immediately obvious from his comment why you might not want that. I am not being rude, just extra explicit about the results. Truth != rudeness.

Comment: As terrinecold mentions, toISOString() is not what you want -- it will most likely convert the date/time you have fed into the Date object to the UTC/Zulu time.

Comment: i hate those nested unnamed function blocks that javascript has turned into these days. So uncivilized.

Answer (score 16):

### Why Not to Use toISOString()

The `<input type='date'>` field takes a value in ISO8601 format ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)), but you should not use the `Date.prototype.toISOString()` function for its value because, before outputting an ISO8601 string, it **converts**/represents the date/time to UTC standard time (read: *changes the time zone*) ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)). Unless you happen to be working in or want that time standard, you will introduce a bug where your date will sometimes, but not always, change.

### Populate HTML5 Date Input from Date Object w/o Time Zone Change

The only reliable way to get a proper input value for `<input type='date'>` without messing with the time zone that I've seen is to manually use the date component getters. We pad each component according to the HTML date format specification ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats)):

```js
let d = new Date();
let datestring = d.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0') + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
document.getElementById('date').value = datestring;

/* Or if you want to use jQuery...
$('#date').val(datestring);
*/
```

```html
<input id='date' type='date'>
```

### Populate HTML5 Date & Time Fields from Date Object w/o Time Zone Change

This is beyond the scope of the original question, but for anyone wanting to populate both date & time HTML5 input fields from a Date object, here is what I came up with:

```js
// Returns a 2-member array with date & time strings that can be provided to an
// HTML5 input form field of type date & time respectively. Format will be
// ['2020-12-15', '01:27:36'].
function getHTML5DateTimeStringsFromDate(d) {

  // Date string
  let ds = d.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0') + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

  // Time string
  let ts = d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');

  // Return them in array
  return [ds, ts];
}

// Date object
let d = new Date();

// Get HTML5-ready value strings
let dstrings = getHTML5DateTimeStringsFromDate(d);

// Populate date & time field values
document.getElementById('date').value = dstrings[0]
document.getElementById('time').value = dstrings[1]

/* Or if you want to use jQuery...
$('#date').val(dstrings[0]);
$('#time').val(dstrings[1]);
*/
```

```html
<input type='date' id='date'>
<input type='time' id='time' step="1">
```

Comment: Great reply and still the best strategy in 2021 as far as I'm aware. For the sake of completeness, the year should be zero-padded too. According to the docs on HTML date strings, years are required to be 4 or more characters. This would be needed when working with years below 1000. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you j08691.  That link was the answer.

To others struggling like me, when they say input is "yyyy-mm-dd" the MEAN it!

You MUST have 4 digits for the year.
You MUST have a dash and no spaces.
You MUST have 2 digits for day and month.

In my example myDate.getMonth for January would only return "1" (actually it returns "0" because for some reason javascript counts months from 0-11).  To get this right I had to do the following:

```
var myDate, day, month, year, date;
myDate = new Date();
day = myDate.getDate();
if (day <10)
  day = "0" + day;
month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10)
  month = "0" + month;
year = myDate.getYear();
date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
$("#date").val(date);
```

I hope this helps others not waste hours like I did testing this before October or before the 10th of the month! LOL

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer based on [Robin Drexlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246394/2570775) but in local time.

```
//Get the local date in ISO format
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
var datestr = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

//Set the field value
var field = document.querySelector('#date');
field.value = datestr;
```

If it's a datetime field you're modifying (as opposed to just the date) don't forget to add the time `T00:00`, or change the substring to 16 characters for example:

```
//Get the local date and time in ISO format
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
var datestr = date.toISOString().substring(0, 16);

//Set the field value
var field = document.querySelector('#datetime');
field.value = datestr;
```

Answer (score 2):

This below code populates the local date . The accepted answer populates UTC date.

```
  var date = new Date();
  field = document.querySelector('#date-id');
  var day = date.getDate();
  if(day<10){ day="0"+day;}

  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  if(month<10){ month="0"+month;}

  field.value = date.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+day;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation points to comment on another answer, so I'll just add a new answer.  And since I'm adding an answer, I'll give more details than I would've in a comment.

There's an easier way to zero pad than all of the juggling that everyone is doing here.

```
var date = new Date();

var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var day   = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
var year  = date.getFullYear();

var htmlDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

console.log("Date: " + htmlDate);
```

Today, the output would be

```
Date: 2020-01-07
```

The code is building a dynamic string by prepending a quoted zero, then taking the last 2 characters with slice(-2).  This way, if the zero makes it 01, the last 2 are 01.  If the zero makes it 011, then the last two are 11.

As for the month starting at zero silliness, you can also add 1 dynamically before prepending the zero and everything still works. You just have to do the math operation before turning it into a string.

As a side note, I've noticed that when you update a date field, you have to hide the field before setting the value and show it after setting.  I don't do this often enough, so I have to re-struggle each time I need to deal with it.  Hopefully this will help someone from the future.

*waves to future people*

Comment: lol ty I needed this