# How to show a date only upto today's date in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a date input box like this:

```
<input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" class="text_search" />
```

This displays the date box up to anywhere in the past and future date. Past date is fine but I don't want to show the future date. For example if today's date is `May 31, 2013`, user can only choose the date upto `May 31, 2013`. How can I do that?

Comment: may be by setting its min and max attributes...

Comment: Use the `max`-Attribute. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html for more information

Comment: But I want today's date to be dynamic so I assume I have to use javascript to calculate the today's date.

Comment: But I want today's date to be dynamic so I assume I have to use javascript to calculate the today's date.

Comment: cant u set max attribute with today's date?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-to-get-current-date-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input Type Date -- Default Value to Today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today)

Comment: Apart from the relatively trivial issue that you would use the `max` attribute to set the last date, this is a duplicate of a question that asks how to make the current date the default in `input type=date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using any jquery ui plugin ? if yes then use following code,

```
$(function() {
    $("#start_date").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});
});
```

Comment: I first used HTML5 which didn't work in firefox so I ended up using Jquery UI datepicker and your solution works. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `max` attribute as in `<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">`. You can use javascript to set this attribute to today or set it on the server side