# setting default date in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set the default date in html5 date element

```
<input type="date" min="1940-01-01" max="2012-12-31" id="datepicker" name="mybirthday" placeholder="Birthdate(MM/DD/YYYY)" />
```

The default date is set to 2012-12-31. How to change that?

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982754/188331

Comment: Hi, please always Google first. Stuff like this is extremely trivial to look up. Thanks.

Comment: I tried that answer. When I give the value attribute with the required date nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Set the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="date" value="1940-01-01" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a value attribute. e.g.  `value="2011-06-15"`

```
<input type="date" min="1940-01-01" max="2012-12-31" id="datepicker" name="mybirthday" placeholder="Birthdate(MM/DD/YYYY)"  value="2011-06-15" />
```

Comment: I tried that. But in chrome when i click on the date picker it is not pointing to the desired value

Comment: No it will prefill the date box with the `value` attribute. The interface is determined by the browser. If you want more control over the datepicker consider using a framework like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or a [bootstrap plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)