# How can i set today date as a default date in html

Tags: php, html

The new HTML5 input types are great.
But is there any way to set the default value of the date field to today's date?
I am working with html and php
i want to set today date as a default date in date field of html5.

how can i do this?

Comment: you can set it with the help of php date function.

Comment: Do not nag people to upvote your questions. It is abusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `input type="date"` is always in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php print(date("Y-m-d")); ?>"/>
```

Comment: which was taken from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today. Have to admit that this is a standard line of code.

Answer (score 2):

Like any HTML input field, the browser will leave it empty unless a default value is specified with the value attribute. HTML5 doesn't provide a way of specifying 'today' in the value.

You can do it with javascript or php.

Here is a sample with PHP :

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
```

Here is a sample with Javascript :

```
document.getElementById('myDate').value = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
```

Here is a sample with jquery :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myDate').val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10));
});​
```

Comment: Thank you ,
it is really helpfull for me