# Set date input type default value to Today, Tomorrow, Anydate?

Tags: jquery, html, date, input

In HTML5 there is not a native way of specifying 'today' in the value attribute. Here is the jQuery code I like very much. How to extend this code to set

- today's date to `var today`
- tomorrow's date to `var tomorrow`
- any date calculated to `var anydate` (calculated/initiated from `var today`?)

and define the following 3 id-s accordingly:

- `#theDate`
- `#theTomorrow`
- `#theAnydate`

HTML

```
<input type="date" id="theDate">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

    var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;       
    $("#theDate").attr("value", today);
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsbin.com/oqekar/2/edit)

Comment: [Here are some examples of how you could able to add default date or customize date using jquery and javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511212/5695622)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Like any HTML input field, the browser will leave it empty unless a default value is specified with the value attribute.
>
> Unfortunately HTML5 doesn't provide a way of specifying 'today' in the `value` attribute (that I can see), only a [RFC3339](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339)  valid date like `2011-09-29`.
>
> <sub>source: [Tak's answer on "HTML5 Input Type Date — Default Value to Today?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982754)</sub>

In that instance, you could potentially write a script to simply `+1` to find **tomorrow's date**, but you would first have to add a default value to your `input id` for **today's date**.

As far as **anydate**? Not entirely sure what you mean there. Like a datepicker?

The question was a bit unclear, but I figured I'd help as much as I could with the info provided.

---

To assign a date via jQuery, you could always do something like this...

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/4XkVE/4/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="date" id="theDate">
```

**jQuery:**

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

$('#theDate').attr('value', today);

alert($('#theDate').attr('value'));
```

---

## EDIT:

Furthermore, to find both of today's date, and tomorrow's date, but ensure the end of the month or end of the year won't affect it, use this instead:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/4XkVE/6/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="date" id="theDate">
<input type="date" id="tomorrowDate">
```

**jQuery**

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var tomday = tomorrow.getDate();
var tommonth = tomorrow.getMonth() + 1;
var tomyear = tomorrow.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
if(tomday<10){tomday='0'+tomday} if(tommonth<10){tommonth='0'+tommonth} tomorrow = tommonth+'/'+tomday+'/'+tomyear;
$('#theDate').attr('value', today);
$('#tomorrowDate').attr('value', tomorrow);
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Explicitly: I need 2 id-s at the and: `#theDate` with value of today, and `#theTomorrow` with value of tomorrow. Please tell me how to alert both #theDate and #theTomorrow simultanously at the end. Thank you.

Comment: The one problem you'll be encountering with `+1` is that if it's the end of the month, it won't reflect accurately. I'll update a solution. Two secs.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if that resolves your issue, or if you can work off of it from there.

Comment: Yes, the issue is the +1 won't reflecting accurately. In fact I would use the `#theDate` and `#tomorrowDate` id-s on a wordpress contact7 form to pre-load 2 date fields in advance before the user start to fill the form. The script I shared initially worked seamlessly providing only the #theDate. But I still cannot make this work. :(

Comment: Sorry. I don't know **wordpress** (you didn't tag it). I find `CMS` systems to be less than reliable. I would encourage you to ask a new question and tag **wordpress**, as that will target people with that skill. Feel free to link your new question to this one. All I know is I answered the question asked. If you would like to mark as accepted (**green checkbox next to voting arrows**), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Nicholas Hazel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275042/nicholas-hazel)'s response and [user113716](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/user113716) answer about [leading zeroes for dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date), here's a concise function to get a date formmated as YYYY-MM-DD and set the value of a "date" type input control.

http://jsfiddle.net/wloescher/2t8v7fnf/2/

**HTML**

```
<div>Today:
    <input type="date" id="theDate" />
</div>
<div>Tomorrow:
    <input type="date" id="theTomorrow" />
</div>
<div>Any Date:
    <input type="date" id="theAnyDate" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Set values
$("#theDate").val(getFormattedDate(today()));
$("#theTomorrow").val(getFormattedDate(tomorrow()));
$("#theAnyDate").val(getFormattedDate(new Date("4/1/12")));

function today() {
    return new Date();
}

function tomorrow() {
    return today().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}

// Get formatted date YYYY-MM-DD
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    return date.getFullYear()
        + "-"
        + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
        + "-"
        + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: If you leave the page open across multiple days your `today` and `tomorrow` will be incorrect. It is probably better for them to be defined as functions so the code is `today()` or `tomorrow()` instead.

Comment: Good point Seph - I've modified code to include use new today() and tomorrow() functions

Answer (score 1):

Use toISOString(), which always returns a "Z" timezone ISO8601 string, and truncate it to just the date.

```
var todayUTC = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10);

var todayLocal = new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toISOString().substr(0,10);

var tomorrowLocal = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toISOString().substr(0,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Very Easy Solution:

```
echo (new DateTime('tomorrow'))->format('Y-m-d'); //-- For tomorrow
echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'); //-- For today
```