# Display Current Date in input[type=“date”] after Add new Row button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

having this as intial code

```
<input type="date" class="closed_road_permit_expiry_date" min="2000-01-01" max="9999-01-31" name="closed_road_permit_expiry_date[]" value="value="2000-01-31" />
```

i tried doing this

```
<input type="date" class="closed_road_permit_expiry_date" min="2000-01-01" max="9999-01-31" name="closed_road_permit_expiry_date[]" id="currentDate" value=getCurrentDate()/>

  function getCurrentDate() {
        document.getElementById("currentDate").valueAsDate = new Date()
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input Type Date -- Default Value to Today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cna run an IIFE to populate the field with the current data

```js
(function getCurrentDate() {
  return document.getElementById('currentDate').valueAsDate = new Date();

}())
```

```html
<input type="date" class="closed_road_permit_expiry_date" min="2000-01-01" max="9999-01-31" name="closed_road_permit_expiry_date[]" id="currentDate" />
```

Comment: it's result is mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

run `getCurrentDate()` function on   `window.onload` not with value of the input

```js
function getCurrentDate() {
  document.getElementById("currentDate").valueAsDate = new Date()
}
window.onload = function() {
  getCurrentDate()
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="closed_road_permit_expiry_date" min="2000-01-01" max="9999-01-31" name="closed_road_permit_expiry_date[]" id="currentDate" />
```

Comment: it should work when I click add row button, then a new row for input including the date should show

Comment: it's result is mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function getCurrentDate() {
       var date = new Date();
       var day = date.getDate();
       var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
       var year = date.getFullYear();
       var datestr = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
       document.getElementById("currentDate").value = datestr;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       getCurrentDate();
    });
```