# How to set a default year value to an input with type date?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, html-input

I'm looking to know if it's possible to have an input of the type date to have the default year as 2017. All I can do is set a default date which includes the day and the month too:

```html
<input type="date" value="2017-12-21">
<br><br>
<input type="date" value="2017-mm-dd">
<br><br>
<input type="date" value="2017">
<br><br>
<input type="date">
```

I want it to display the day as `dd`, the month as `mm` and the year as `2017`.

Comment: If you look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982754/381802), you will see that the input type `date` must be [RFC3339](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339) compliant. Which means you must always enter a full and valid date. Why not set it to `2017-01-01`?

Comment: @Eric That's what I was afraid of since I didn't found anywhere how to do this. It's not too big of a deal, it just would be nice if there was a way since the user can type 2017 and have it what I want as default. The min/max trick in the answers are an ok trick but not what I need as it takes the option to pick another year.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="date"  min="2017-01-01" max="2017-12-30">
```

Try min and max properties like this. It should work

Comment: That's not the OP is asking.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, as a work around, if all else fails...

Here's the **[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/subhojit/3c24b05a/)**

```
<form>
 <div>
  <input type="date" min="2017-01-01" max="2017-12-31">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not what he is look for this is what he has sure

Comment: Closest workaround but it takes the option to pick other years so unless there's a secret way that nobody knows, the correct answer is Eric's comment.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought you're telling about taking 2017 as the default year. Didn't thought about changing the year fact. so just given this solution. mistaken.