# Default date in datetime-local input - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I set the default date in the datetime-local field?

This is my HTML :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 photo-container" ng-repeat="photo in selectedPhotos track by $index" ng-if="add">
            <input id="myDate" type="datetime-local" name="date[]" ng-model="form.date[$index]">
            <img ng-src="{{photo}}" class="thumb">
        </div>
```

I tried to set the default date in the controller for ng-model, i.e. 
`$scope.form.date[0] = $filter("date")(Date.now(), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');` but it doesnt work.
So, How can I set the default date for each input?

The main point is that the date should be set for every $index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input Type Date -- Default Value to Today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/html5-input-type-date-default-value-to-today). Basically, use the standard ISO format.

Comment: This is not duplicate, because I must assign date to model with $index. I have a problem with assigning this.

Answer (score 0):

Its generally difficult to play with datetime-local, but you can do this to initialize the model values -

```
var myDate = new Date().toISOString();
    $scope.myDemo = myDate.substring(0,myDate.length-1);
```

[check the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3rhnyof/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will check this answer tomorrow. But I have yet one ask. 
How do I assign data in the controller to my model from the view? My model  is : ng-model="form.date[$index]"

Comment: Do a foreach loop on selectPhotos in js and set every model equal to myDate