# How to set default value or current date to the input[type=“date”]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select today date in input type="date"

```
<input id="date" type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, to get today's date in Javascript you need to write `new Date()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today

Comment: Do you want to set your input tag show today's date as a defualt then you should edit your question."How to set input type date's default value to today?" @ankita

Answer (score 4):

Pure JavaScript-version of filling the date of today in a html5-input of type date:

```js
let dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
dateInput.valueAsDate = new Date();
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: @ankita Good to hear that your problem is now solved. If this answer provided the information you needed to solve the problem please accept it. (See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))