# Defaulting a date field in ColdFusion

Tags: html, coldfusion, cfml, html-input, coldfusion-2018

I want to default a date input control to today

```
<cfoutput>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtStart" value="#LSDateFormat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#" required />
    <br />
    My Date: #LSDateFormat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#
</cfoutput>
```

All I get out of this is

[image]

Is there a way to get it to default to today?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: `type="date"` fields are open for browser to implement based on browser/system locale/settings. Also if the `value` attribute should be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Then the default value will appear in the input field(formatted based on the browser setting).

Comment: This is not a dup because I am asking about how to set the value as opposed to how it is displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: @Alex That is indeed a dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like below ( Set mask as 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) , It will show default value as the current date for your input date field.

```
<cfoutput>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtStart" value="#LSDateFormat(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd')#" required />
    <br />
    My Date: #LSDateFormat(now(), 'mm/dd/yyyy')#
</cfoutput>
```

**Code result as screenshot**

[image]

Comment: This is very useful. I didn't know about the lsDateFormat() function until now. Thanks a bunch.