# How to set default date value to input of type 'date'?

Tags: php, date, input

I have a date value in `PHP` variable `$date`which want to show in the input having type date with following code:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" name="date">
```

I want to show the value which is in `$date` variable in the input textbox of date. Also, user should be able to pick the value from the date picker, which is working fine, but i want a date should be there.
I looked at previous questions, they assign the today's value, but i want to use the value i have in `$date` variable.

Comment: Should most likely still be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today, even if the value you want to set is _not_ today. The rest of the info in there is still what is mainly relevant to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: This is a valid question for "PHP" and not a duplicate of the mentioned question @04FS

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like**

```
<?php 
$timestamp = time();
$date = date( "Y-m-d", $timestamp );
?>

<input type="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" name="date">
```

**Explanation**

`date( "Y-m-d", $timestamp )` formats a timestamp to the appropriate format ( e.g. 2019-11-29 ).

**Resources**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 0):

Try RMo solution or try.

`<input name="date" type="date" value="<?php echo date('F d, Y'); ?>" />`

**Where:**

- F stands for Month in words
- d stands for days in number,
- Y stands for year in 4 digit number.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#date_strings