# Setting the input value of a form element from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My form element looks like

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-xl">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">You Can Edit This Item</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form role="form" id="modal-form">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="receivingdate">Receiving Date</label>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="receivingdate" placeholder="Select Receiving Date" required>
                                        </div>
```

from javascript I just want to set `receivingdate` to `x/x/x`

```js
 var form = document.getElementById('modal-form').getElementsByClassName('form-group');
```

Not sure why this does not work.

Comment: Do you want to change `dd/mm/yyyy` to `x/x/x`??

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("receivingdate").value = "x/x/x";`
Edit: Scratch that. It won't let you put x/x/x as a value because it doesn't conform to a date format, e.g. dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-MM-dd. You'll need to put an actual date in there if you want a default.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today#comment83721109_6982754), you can use this trick to get the default todays date into the right format to set it using the value property of the element.
`document.getElementById("water-volume").value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var form = document.getElementById('modal-form').getElementsByClassName('form-group');
```

Does not work because your `document.getElementById('modal-form')` gets a specific element while `.getElementsByClassName('form-group')` can't be used to get children of that element. Additionally, the form variable would simply hold the element retrieved from the document.

If you absolutely need to get all .form-group elements under #modal-form, then you can use

```
var elements = document.querySelector("#modal-form .form-group");
```

If you're just trying to set the #receivingdate date element, then you can use the value property of that element.

```
document.getElementById("receivingdate").value = "2019-12-10";
```

Note that this will require a string in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`. You can't set that box to `x/x/x` literally, but setting it to the above value will give you `10/12/2019` or `12/10/2019` depending on your locale.

If you simply want it to default to todays date, then you can use

```
document.getElementById("water-volume").value = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
```

Where en-CA sets todays date to the string format of Canadian English date format, which just so happens to be the format that a date element requires.

If you want to retrieve the current date, you would simply use

```
var date = document.getElementById("receivingdate").value;
```

And you'd put that inside an event handler like on change.

If you're looking to do more advanced manipulation of the DOM, then I'd look into [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). More robust date formatting can be done using [date.js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs).

Comment: The reason why I posted here is because, I have mutiple forms in my html that has the same name. I need to get the ```recieivngdate``` of ```modal-form``` hence ```document.getElementById("receivingdate").value``` will not work because there are multiple elements with that ID.

Comment: @sakib11 you can't have multiple elements on the same page with the same ID. ID needs to be unique to the element. Only one is allowed at a time. Classes are allowed to have multiple elements. So you would need to put the ID on the modal and then put a class on the input element. Then you can use `document.querySelector("#elementID .inputClass")` to get the specific input. Where elementID is the ID of the modal and the inputClass is the class of the input.

Or you could make them both IDs so `document.querySelector("#modalID #receivingdate")`.

Comment: that explains quite a lot. Thanks

Comment: @sakib11 Feel free to pick the right answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

f you just want to get value of receivingdate.Try this

```
document.getElementById('receivingdate').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var form = document.getElementById('receivingdate').value;
  console.log(form)
```

})