# how to set today's date in input date html

Tags: php, html

in HTML, working with input date, I need to display today's date in input date

```
<tr>
  <td>Date</td>
  <td><input id='input-date' type='date' value=getDate() onchange=''></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Answer (score 0):

this code work very well and simply try this code

```
  <input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="current_date">
```

Comment: made but there is a mistake, kassa.php:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at getDate (kassa.php:130)
    at window.onload (kassa.php:135)

Comment: Try the new code. Achieved in php.