# How can i give default values to the first input?

Tags: javascript

Hi there can you help me solving this,
I have this code here

```
<div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="" tabindex="0" styling="[object Object]" 
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" aria-label="date" aria-invalid="false" 
      valid="1" class="needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 
      fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="" tabindex="0" styling="[object Object]" 
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" aria-label="date" aria-invalid="false" 
      valid="1" class="needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 
      fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i give the input value today's date, with pure javascript, i cant add manually and can't add other classes name or id's because its automatically generated.
Thanks,

Edited,
The script i want to include is in a shopify theme, and the inputs are on a pop-up, maybe this will help you more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: If the input element is the first input element on the page with the class of "test", you can get a reference to it with simple `document.querySelector('input.test')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```js
let date = new Date();
document.getElementsByClassName('needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1')[0].value = date.getFullYear() +'/'+ date.getMonth() +'/'+ date.getDate();
document.getElementsByClassName('needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1')[1].value = date.getFullYear() +'/'+ date.getMonth() +'/'+ date.getDate();
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="" tabindex="0" styling="[object Object]" 
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" aria-label="date" aria-invalid="false" 
      valid="1" class="needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 
      fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="" tabindex="0" styling="[object Object]" 
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" aria-label="date" aria-invalid="false" 
      valid="1" class="needsclick TextInput__FormStyledTextInput-sc-1o6de9f-0 
      fsIKy kl-private-reset-css-Xuajs1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's appreciated that you'd read the entire question before answering: "_can't add other classes name or id's_" ...

Comment: Same even for you, its shows an error on console.log typerror, thanks for trying to help

Comment: can you please check out again my question, its refreshed

Comment: @EndritShabani I updated the HTML according to your update. The JavaScript code could be improved with a loop if you care about dynamic code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` method to get the elements with class "test" and then use "Date()" to pass the date.

```js
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("test")
inputs[0].value = new Date();
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input class="test" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <input class="test" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for trying to help me, its showing an error on console.log typeerror

Comment: @EndritShabani If you run the snippet on this answer, you can see it works perfectly, please focus on your task. As you said, "_[input is] automatically generated_", don't try to access the element before it exists.

Comment: Can i delay the script to be called after 2-3 seconds ?

Comment: To execute after a delay, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: can you please check out again my question, its refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (let i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].classList.contains('test')) {
        let now = new Date();
        inputs[i].value = now.getFullYear() +'/'+ now.getMonth() +'/'+ now.getDate();
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <input class="test" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
   <div>
      <input class="test" type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but, idk its not working.

Comment: Have you any error to share ? It's work perfectly on my GoogleChrome 87.0.4280.88

Comment: can you please check out again my question, its refreshed

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputs = documemt.querySelectorAll('.test')
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = new Date().getDate()
}
```

**EDIT**

If you only want a single input to display the date:

```
inputs[index]  = new Date().getDate()
```

Comment: Why the loop, OP wants the first value only.

Comment: He didn't say that tho, but if so, just drop the loop and specify the index instead

Answer (score 0):

var now = new Date();

document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].value = now;

document.getElementsByClassName("test")[1].value = now;