# document.getElementById().value not returning a value

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to just access the value from my date input

```js
let object = document.getElementById('tripdateinput').value;
console.log(object);
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="tripdateinput" type="date" name="tripdate" required>
```

but when i try to console.log(object) it returns as empty. This is also only happening with my date inputs my normal text inputs are working.

Comment: Your input doesn't have an initial value so it's empty, you probably need a default value: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6982692/2333214

Comment: Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question then it will get upvotes.

Comment: Yes thank you, adding a eventlistener did the job!

Comment: Why do so many people assume `value` being an observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this script to get your selected date value:

```js
document.getElementById('tripdateinput').addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="tripdateinput" type="date" name="tripdate" required>
```

What this does is create an `eventListener` to your input field. Similar to a single `onChange` `eventHandler`, this will get the `event` when your input field changes it's values.

Your code should look like this:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="tripdateinput" type="date" name="tripdate" required>

<script>
  document.getElementById('tripdateinput').addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please write in the description of your answer what changes you made to solve the problem.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I've added one, thanks for the heads up.