# How to set the input date to current date in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input type="date" name="today" id="today" value="Date()">
```

i have done this but this does'nt work I want that the input should display the current date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: that is because of format for sure

Answer (score 2):

You can also use JS ***Date() Object***:

```js
document.getElementById('date').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type='date' id='date'>
</body>
</html>
```