# <input type="date"> Not Showing Value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my react app, I have an  that looks like:

```js
<input
  type="date"
  className="form-control form-control-lg"
  onFocus={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "text")}
  onBlur={(e) => (e.currentTarget.type = "date")}
  name="start_date"
  placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
  defaultValue={projectDetails.start_date}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

I am passing in the value "05-06-2004". I can see the value in the dev tools inspector, but I am not seeing it in the actual input. Any idea why?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the correct format to set the value is `MM-DD-YYYY`? What if you try `YYYY-MM-DD` or `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: Your date format is faulty. See [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: Thank you both - I appreciate it!