# How to make $date show on input type="date"

Tags: php, date, input

All the "date" in my database are of the following format: 'd-m-Y' (E.g. 09-03-2022)

I want have a field with input type=date, so user can modify the date.

I use the following code to pull data:

```
$date      = "<input type=\"date\" id=\"date\" size= \"50%;\" name=\"date\" value=\"$res[date]\" >";

...
<thead> <th>Date </th> <td>$date </td> </thead>
```

But my inputbox is showing dd/mm/yyyy instead of the actual date.

[image]

What formatting do I need to do to make my actual date show on the inputbox?

I have tried the following but doesn't work:

```
$date      = "<input type=\"date\" id=\"date\" size= \"50%;\" name=\"date\" value=\"date('d-m-Y',$res[date])\" >";
```

Comment: What is the result of the code you've posted? The first one (the second won't work since you can't put PHP functions in strings like that.) You need to format the date before adding it, and why not format it in the same format as it expects (using / instead of -)? Right click on the page and then "view page source". Side note: _"All the "date" in my database are of the following format: 'd-m-Y' (E.g. 09-03-2022)"_ - That's not a good way of storing dates. When storing dates, set the column as a "date" type in the database, which expects the dates to be in the format `Y-m-d`.

Comment: Why are you storing the HTML of the "input" field in a variable...? You can just concatenate your date from the database with HTML like that `<thead> <th>Date </th><td><input type="date" id="date" size="50%;" name="date" value="<? echo $res[date]; ?>"></td> </thead>`

Comment: The value of a date input has to be in YYYY-MM-DD format (or empty)

Comment: `All the "date" in my database are of the following format: 'd-m-Y' (E.g. 09-03-2022)`...why are you storing dates as text in your database?? That's a bad design mistake. Use a DATE or DATETIME column type, that's what it's there for. Dates are not strings (except when you're showing them to humans or serialising them for transmission). Your current storage format makes it impossible to properly compare, sort, or filter the database rows by date, and - as you've found - more difficult to extract the date info in a useful way for usage elsewhere.

Comment: Anyway https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date makes it quite clear that the `value` attribute must be a date serialised into YYYY-MM-DD format. It's unclear why you tried to use d-m-Y therefore, or why you don't know what format to use. Always read the manual.

Comment: The "date" values are stored into the database using the formula $date = date('d-m-Y'); When I look at the SQL tables, the date fields look like 09-03-2022, for one example. So when I SELECT from database and display the date, it looks like 09-03-2022. But how do I display it on the "input type=date" field? The input field is showing me dd/mm/yyyy...
Not 09/03/2022

Comment: @Mohammad Salehi answered your questions it seems to me in his answer no...? Even if your dates are not stored correctly you can do a query and use date_format it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a wrong format to your date input.
Date input must fill with RFC3339 formatted text, you can [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982754/6934036) about it.

To change your current format to `Y-m-d` format, you can use below code:

```php
DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $dateInput)->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you are using MySQL, it uses `YYYY-MM-DD` format for date type column, so, saving the date with `Y-m-d` from PHP to MySQL `date` field seems to be the correct way.

Comment: Thanks. After much testing, I was able to get the following code to work: 
$date1  =   date_create("$res[date]");
$date2  =   date_format($date1,"Y-m-d");
$date = "<input type=\"date\" ... value=\"$date2\" >";

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the reason why the date is not displaying on my input field is becuz it is in String datatype and need to format to DATE.

```
$date1  =   date_create("$res[date]");
$date2  =   date_format($date1,"Y-m-d");
$date   = "<input type=\"date\" id=\"date\" size= \"50%;\" name=\"date\" value=\"$date2\" >";
```

With this, I can also do the same for TIME

```
$time1  =   date_create("$res[time]");
$time2  =   date_format($time,"H:i:s");
$time   = "<input type=\"time\" id=\"time\" size= \"50%;\" name=\"time\" value=\"$time2\" >";
```

Comment: Mark your answer as 'accepted answered' if it solved your problem.

Comment: You answer your question "believing that the reason is that" but these are indications that many of us gave in the comments and @MohammadSalehi in his answer, no...?