# How to have HTML Input Date default to today date while hiding the seconds Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

```js
/*
// * Setting a default value for the date box
document.getElementById("DATE").valueAsDate = new Date(); */
```

```html
        <input type="datetime-local" id="DATE" value="2023-05-01T11:00" name="Date"
                                                placeholder="" class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
```

So if I uncomment the Javascript below I can set my value to today date but it over ride my value that I have set that hides the second. Is there any way to modify the javascript code I have so that I can still omit the seconds while having today date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set input type date's default value to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982692/how-to-set-input-type-dates-default-value-to-today)

Comment: Unfortunately not I still need the time just not down to the exact second. Using Date instead of datetime local is not exact enough

Comment: ```
    let dateInput = document.getElementById("DATE");
    dateInput.value = dateInput.value.split("T")[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom method to format the date to a string and set the value like so:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const hours = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const minutes = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}`;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("DATE").value = formatDate(new Date());
});
```